# black screen when return to last activity

Tags: android, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

I have an app which render (with `GLES2`) terrain and everything works as expected.
When I press the home button and then switch back to my activity - the screen is black and never return to itself as before.
Why is it happen?
should I save any data before I go to home screen?
 something else that I missed?

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig config) {

    try {

        if (m_pViewport == null)
        {
            CreateMapDevice();
            CreateGridCoordinates();
            CreateNativeRasterLayer();
            CreateRawVectorLayer();
            CreateMapTerrain();
            CreateOverlayManager();
            CreateOverlay();
            m_eDisplayType = EDisplayType.EDT_2D;
            CreateViewport();
            CreatePicObject();
            CreateWorldPicObject();
            CreateTelemetryText();

        }
        else
        {
            m_pViewport.RemoveTerrain(m_pTerrain);
            CreateNativeRasterLayer();
            CreateMapTerrain();
            m_pViewport.AddTerrain(m_pTerrain);
        }

           IMcGLDeviceCamera.Create(m_Context);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should share some code of your activity

Comment: which part of it? it pretty long

Comment: The part where is create your terrain

Comment: I added the code yo asked @Cochi

Comment: Do you call this method in oncreate function ?

Comment: OnPause->
OnResume->
OnSurfaceCreate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138231/discussion-between-cochi-and-arii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your OpenGLES context is destroyed when your app goes into the background.

I think you probably need to use [setPreserveEGLContextOnPause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(boolean)).